# What happened to the Goblin-Slayer tagged questions?

Tags: discussion

A few weeks ago I saw 4 or 5 Goblin Slayer questions.  Today I looked at the tag to look up something, and all I find [is one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goblin-slayer).  I checked [another spelling](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goblinslayer) and there are 0 questions ins in that tag.  I also checked the Japanese romanji of [Goburin Sureiyā](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=Goburin%20Sureiy%C4%81), and found nothing.

Did the questions get removed?  If I recall, most of the Goblin Slayer questions were by the same user.

Comment: Could you estimate the date range instead of "a few weeks ago"? The [tag info](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/goblin-slayer/info) states that the created date is the same as the only question. Perhaps you're mistaking the questions with other *isekai*, like [*Reincarnated as Slime*](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reincarnated-as-a-slime?sort=newest) in which RichF posted 6 questions quite recently?

Comment: That could be it, that avatar looks familiar, and the question count seems close enough.